# Python equivalent of PowerShell where-object

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

I have a JSON dataset returned from a web request that looks something like this:

```
[{'name': 'Reference', 'unit': 'Volts'},
 {'name': 'House', 'unit': 'Watts'},
 {'name': 'House', 'unit': 'Watt-Hours'},
 {'name': 'House', 'unit': 'Volts'},
 {'name': 'Solar', 'unit': 'Watts'},
 {'name': 'Solar', 'unit': 'Watt-Hours'},
 {'name': 'Solar', 'unit': 'Volts'}]
```

I'm looking for a simple way of returning an iterable list, filtered by unit. In PowerShell, I'd use:

```
$list = $data | Where-Object { $_.unit -eq 'Watts' }
```

Unfortunately, I've very little experience in Python. I *think* I could use `filter()` with a lambda expression, but just can't seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the act of posting the question leads me to the answer:

```
list = filter(lambda x: x['unit'] == 'Watts', data)
```

Comment: Why is this tagged PowerShell, when your request is specifically Python? There is a place to ask Python questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python